# How to generate correct URLs in mailer templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, mailer

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to properly generate URLs in HTML email messages. In my environment file I set

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'my_site.org' }
```

In the email view file (`.html.erb`) I state

```
<%= link_to @user.name, users_url(@user) %>
```

When I go to see the received email the generated URL is `http://users/1`, of course no correct. So, **how can I generate correct URLs in mailer templates so to have `http://my_site.org/users/1` links in body messages?**

---

I also tryed to set the `default_url_options` in my `mailer.rb` file

```
class MyCustom::Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default_url_options[:host] = 'my_site.org'

  def test_sending
    ...
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`users_path` is the relative path (/users/1). For an email, you want the absolute path, so use `users_url(@user)`, which will give http://myapp.com/users/1 instead.

Comment: What if the route I'm using doesn't have any helper method such as `thing_url` or `thing_path` ?

Answer (score 1):

your action_mailer setting is correct.

But you should be using _url and not _path for the link_to,

```
<%= link_to @user.name, users_url(@user) %>
```

Comment: You have right, but to be fair will choose I will accept the first answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See that you set the config option.  To be sure it uses the absolute path use:

```
<%= link_to, "My Profile", users_url(:only_path => false, @user) %>
```

OR set the host specifically in the link:

```
<%= link_to, "My Profile", users_url(:host => "example.com", @user) %>
```

It is explained here:

[ActionView Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)